# Why can't I use MySQL 'year' data type in my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

According to MySQL reference manual there is a data type as "year". I wanted to use it with my rails app but when i run `rails db:migrate` , it fails and says :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x000056047e3c6120>
```

Create_book migration file:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.year :release
      t.references :genre, foreign_key: true
      t.references :author, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post little log for which line of migration it is failing? Get code of migration for which it fails.

Comment: @ray added migration file to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `DateTime` then `t.datetime` will work for you.

If you are storing year only, it can be stored in integer, use `t.integer` which will simply store year. Maybe mysql have datatype `year` but here your ruby object for mysql connection adapter do not have.

Comment: ruby object for mysql connection adapter do not have. Got it thanks.